# Is there a way with javascript to split a korean word into it's components?

Tags: javascript, cjk

Is there a way in javascript to split a word such as

`"팔꿈"`

into an array

`[ㅍ,ㅏ,ㄹ,ㄱ,ㄱ,ㅜ,ㅁ]`?

I'm trying to check for correct inputs for a word rather than the whole word itself.

this package has helped
https://github.com/e-/Hangul.js

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, but close enough, by using normalization form D (NFD), i.e. canonical decomposition:

```
console.log(Array.from("팔꿈".normalize ('NFD')));    // returns ['ᄑ', 'ᅡ', 'ᆯ', 'ᄁ', 'ᅮ', 'ᆷ']
```

Comment: That's pretty interesting, I guess I should have added this in my original comment, but I'm trying to compare inputs with a word. So I can check the accuracy on each input rather than the completed character.